# Complex criteria Opportunity Validation Rule

Tags: administration, validation-rule

I have a requirement of restricting the opportunity ownership change these are my conditions

1. Opportunity stage =closed won ,Closed lost
2. (we have a Formula Field called 'Team' which is based on Opportunity owner)
   If team == 'India' give access to (x,y), A, B, C(only when closed won) when closed lost give access to A, B, C
3. if team='us' give access to (N, T), A, B, C(only when closed won), when closed lost give access to A, B, C

Here A, B, C, X, Y, N, T are users among them B, X, Y, N, T is having same profile(along with that there some other people so I have used profiles as well username so that only particular person will get access)
The stage is picklist value so there need to be one more criterion and join the rule with 'OR' I'll take care of that But when closed-won I have these many conditions does it result in ambiguity by system

I'm breaking my head that how to join all these even I have Used AND(OR) with IF but Rule is not working as expected can anyone help on this or an idea how to get this work

VR: version 1

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Closed Won'),ISCHANGED(OwnerId),   
OR(PRIORVALUE(Team__c)<>'India Team',$User.FirstName<>'A',$Profile.Name<> 'B',$Profile.Name<>'C'
,Team__c =='India Team',$User.FirstName<>'A',$Profile.Name<>'B',$Profile.Name<>'C',$User.FirstName <>'N',$Profile.Name <>'T')
 && PRIORVALUE(Team__c)== 'Banglore Team',$User.FirstName<>'A',$Profile.Name<> 'SB',$Profile.Name<>'C')
```

Comment: The question is not clear. When closed won and closed lost the ownership will be given to different users, right? In the text both refer to A,B,C. And also the profiles should be considered - can we not simply assume that the users have the correct profiles? What am I missing here?

Comment: please use [edit] and format the VR to be readable